# How to implement multiple project in a repository on GitHub with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I want to need many project folders on my repository by using only the Android Studio tool.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk7zw.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple trick you just need to put your whole project into another folder and push that folder into Github.